# Problem with edge loop on bevelled edges

Tags: edges, bevel

see below - I bevelled an edge (no modifier) and when I insert an edge loop, it merges some of the edges. Any idea how to solve this ? (Model ahs apply scale and no internal faces). Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share this part of your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Sure, i went ahead a bit but same issue applies - I also can't seem to put any edge loop on the curved button too...

Answer (score 5):

I think it has nothing to do with the loopcut operation but the fact that when you slide the edge the vertices will merge because of the *Auto Merge* option that is enabled, and the short threshold, maybe disable it or decrease the threshold:

[image]

Comment: Absolutely was this! I think because the components are so small, the default threshold is more towards bigger elements - anyway thanks so much

Comment: oops thanks Robin for the edit  ;)